# How do I change the Dropbox (for Business) location on a headless Linux server

Tags: linux, sync, dropbox, symbolic-link

Im trying to adjust the path Dropbox syncs to on a headless installation. I use a Synology, so there`s no way to connect a monitor.

By default Dropbox syncs all data in /root/Dropbox (Company_name). It also creates a symlink: Dropbox -> /root/Dropbox (Company_name) in /root

The Dropbox contains lets say folders A, B and C

I want to have the Dropbox contents directly in /volume1 so the full path to folder A should be /volume1/A

Can this achieved using symlinks? It looks like all other options are not working anymore such as editing the path in dropbox.db. I have an empty dropbox.db. host.db and unlink.db are both protected using a password.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `mount` to bind local directory into another location, ie:

```
# mount --bind /root/Dropbox(name) /volume1
```

but you have to bind every time you reboot. there is more about mount bind in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount.

or as you pointed out you can make another symlink.

Comment: /volume1 is already mounted on the system and contains data. I need the Dropbox data to coexist with the local data. Does a bind mount work in this scenario?

Comment: oh :/ no, mount will "cover" existing content in that case. but mount can bind single files too, so you can bind all content from dropbox directory one by one (dirs and files) to /volume1.

Comment: Thanks. I used this command mount --bind /root/Dropbox(name) /volume1/A 
I would expect this mount to show up as /volume1/A among the other files that already reside on volume1.. However /volume1 now only "contains" the A directory. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: that should not happen. actually i just tested it myself (i just remembered reading about binding a file, never did it). and you need a mountpoint (destination) for the file or directory you want to bind . so it's not enough to `mount --bind /root/Dropbox/A /volume1/A`. directory A has to already exist in /volume1. the same goes with files. so before `mount --bind /root/Dropbox/some_file /volume1/some_file` you have to ie `touch /volume1/some_file` to make a mountpoint for mount. it's getting more and more complicated, sorry, no clue how to solve it easier.